# TypeORM ColumnTypeUndefined Error trouble shooting steps?

Tags: typescript, webpack, typeorm

Adding TypeORM to a vanilla Javascript project but getting this error. The project is packaged with webpack, built from an ejected create-react-app.

```
ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for Commodity#name is not defined and
cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported "reflect-metadata on
top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported). If
you are using JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must explicitly provide a
column type.
```

Followed the instructions. Saw that reflect is in the global scope. Still getting the error. What steps would be recommended from here?

Answer (score 0):

@Column() must set a type,like @Column('text',{nullable:true}).

More infos at https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2897